# Use a Groovy trait in a Grails controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to make use of a Groovy trait in a Grails controller as per the following:

```
trait ColumnSelectionController {
    def selectColumns() {
        //Do something here
    }
}

class MyController implements ColumnSelectionController {
    def index() {
        //Calculate list model
    }
}
```

When I run this in Grails however, the "selectColumns" action is not visible and I get a 404 response from Grails. I suspect that there is something that I need to do to the trait such that the methods defined inside of it are recognized as actions in the implementing class. Anybody know what that might be?

EDIT 1:

Further information: the trait is defined in src/groovy, not in grails-app/controllers, therefore it isn't defined as an Artefact.

EDIT 2:

In addition, if I change the trait to a class, mark it with the @Artefact annotation and change MyController to extend this class, everything works as expected. Attempting to use the @Artefact annotation on the trait does nothing (no big surprise).

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Also, what version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.4.3 and Groovy 2.3.3. Traits work fine in other parts of the app and all trait methods are visible as methods, they just are not wired to action endpoints.

Comment: did you resolve this problem? we have the same issue

Comment: I did not get an answer, nor have I found a work around. The trait contributed methods are simply not wired as controller actions. I think this is a feature that is coming in Grails 3.0 based on the comments they make on reimplementing using traits. They are notably using Groovy 2.4 though.

Comment: It works if you add "@grails.web.Action" annotation to trait method. Trait must be in src/groovy. If you name it as controller and add to grails-app/controllers it will fail because of compile-time injected private/protected fields and methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just define @Action annotation over defined method in trait, this will make this method working as Action for controller(when traits get implemented)

```
import grails.web.Action

trait ColumnSelectionController {

  @Action
  def selectColumns() {
     //Do something here
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an error that complains grails is trying to call the @Action method in the trait statically.  No signature of method: static <actionName>